# Using Kivy Popup

Tags: python, kivy

I want to use two descadents of class *Popup* in one function (principle of the problem is in next code). How must I solve it?

```
class TextInputPopup(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TextInputPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        . . . 
        . . .
        . . .
    def get_used button(self):
         . . .
         if test == 8:  # test for exaple
             return 'yes'
         else:
             return 'no'

class SaveAs(BoxLayout):
    teinp = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SaveAs, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_call_popup(self):
        poti = TextInputPopup('Directory Manager', 'DirName')
        poti.open()
        poti.bind(on_dismiss=self.next_step)
        result = poti.get_used_button()

        if result == 'yes':

            poti2 = TextInputPopup('File Manager', 'FileName')
            poti2.open()
            poti2.bind(on_dismiss=self.next_step2)
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create two pop ups at one time? Because I don't think Kivy actually lets you do that?